# C++ method forwarding

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, operator-overloading, perfect-forwarding

I need to implement a class Container which acts exactly as the contained template class:

```
template <typename T>
class Container {
public:
      //...
private:
      // T data_;
};
```

`T` can be either a predefined type (e.g., `int`) or a user-defined type.

The purpose is to intercept any read/write operations done on the contained type.

I've succesfully implemented most operators, and it works.

However, when I need to access methods specific of the contained class T, it doesn't work:

```
Container<myclass> a;
a.myclass_specific_method();
```

The reason is that Container obviously doesn't have such methods. Moreover, since T is a template, its methods cannot be known in advance.

I guess there is no solution to this problem, even with C++11, because `operator .` cannot be overloaded. Therefore, the only possible approach is to always rely on `operator->` like smart pointers do.

Can you confirm ?

Comment: Can't you provide an accessor (getter) for `data_` and use it like: `a.get().myclass_specific_method();`?

Comment: No, I can't. I want the Container to be as much as possible transparent to the programmer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a class type `T`, this will act a lot like a `T`:

```
template<class T, class=void>
struct Container : public T { // inheritance MUST be public
  using T::T;
  Container() = default; // or override
  Container( Container const& ) = default; // or override
  Container( Container && ) = default; // or override
  Container& operator=( Container const& ) = default; // or override
  Container& operator=( Container && ) = default; // or override
  // here, we override any method we want to intercept

  // these are used by operators:
  friend T& get_t(Container& self){return self;}
  friend T const& get_t(Container const& self){return self;}
  friend T&& get_t(Container&& self){return std::move(self);}
  friend T const&& get_t(Container const&& self){return std::move(self);}
};
```

for a non-class `T`, we detect it and use a different implementation:

```
template<class T>
struct Container<T, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_class<T>{}>::type > {
  T t;
  Container() = default; // or override
  Container( Container const& ) = default; // or override
  Container( Container && ) = default; // or override
  Container& operator=( Container const& ) = default; // or override
  Container& operator=( Container && ) = default; // or override

  // these are used by operators:
  friend T& get_t(Container& self){return self.t;}
  friend T const& get_t(Container const& self){return self.t;}
  friend T&& get_t(Container&& self){return std::move(self).t;}
  friend T const&& get_t(Container const&& self){return std::move(self).t;}
};
```

finally, we go off and override *every operator we can find* in a SFINAE friendly way, where the operator only participates in overload resolution if `get_t(Container)` would work in its place in the operator.  This should all be done in a namespace, so the operators are found via ADL.  An overload of `get_t` that returns its argument unchanged could be useful to massively reduce the number of overloads.

This could be another 100 or more lines of code.

Users of `Container<T>` can bypass the `Container<T>` and get the underlying `T` in the above system.

Comment: Thank you. However, besides the  `std::enable_if_t` which likely should be   `std::enable_if`, a simple `Container<int>` does not compile as it complains with `error: base type ‘int’ fails to be a struct or class type`. Can you check ?

Comment: @claudio `typename std::enable_if<?>::type` replaces `std::enable_if_t<?>` in a C++11 compiler.  Missing the type/typename makes it fail to do what it is supposed to (redirect non-class, like `int`, to 2nd implementation)

Comment: thank you again. So, why don't you change the code so it can run on any C++11 compiler ?

Comment: @claudio because it looks less ugly in C++14, and I'm currently chatting to you on my phone, hence lazy.  Feel free to edit corrections in!

Comment: I felt that it was better to write it in C++11 rather than C++14, so it also works on older compilers. I've changed it. Many thanks again.

Comment: @claudio you missed a `typename` before the `enable_if` I think

Comment: Forgotten. Now fixed.

Answer (score 15):

The C++ committee is currently looking into "overloaded `operator .`" for future revisions of the language.

However, in your specific case, you can simply inherit from the type.

```
template <typename T>
class Container : private T {
public:
    using T::something_publicly_accessible;
};
```

Comment: if the methods are only from a known set, then SFINAE could be used

Comment: Good to know that the committee is (finally) considering overloading of `operator .`
Something I forgot to say is the purpose of the class: intercept any read/write operation on the contained type. Unfortunately, I cannot inherit from the type because when I implement `operator=(T other)` the call to statement `T::operator=(other);` fails for predefined types (e.g., `int`).

Comment: Yes, overloading `operator. ` would be nice ... shared references! Can you point to some status?

Comment: @AmiTavory This isn't the CRTP.  CRTP is upside down.

Comment: @Claudio Perhaps you should wrap built-in types in a proxy class and then inherit from the proxy. The simplest way to define a proxy to a built-in type `T` is to provide `template< typename t > struct proxy { t obj; operator t & () { return obj; } operator t const & () const { return obj; } };`. The conversion will enable the built-in operators to work, so you don't need to overload them yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Are you opposed to having a getter for the inner `data` member? If no, then you can use something like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
class Container
{
public:
    Container(T _data) : data{_data} {}
    T GetData() const { return data; }
private:
    T data;
};

int main()
{
    Container<std::string> c{"foo"};
    std::cout << c.GetData().size();
}
```

Otherwise you could internally access the method, and it will only compile if such a method exists for `T`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
class Container
{
public:
    Container(T _data) : data{_data} {}
    std::size_t size() const { return data.size(); }
private:
    T data;
};

int main()
{
    Container<std::string> c{"foo"};
    std::cout << c.size();
}
```

So this latter method would work if `T` was e.g. `std::string`, `std::vector`, `std::list`, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, `T` can be even a user-defined class. Moreover, I can't use a getter because the API must be as more transparent to the programmer as possible (less invasive as possible).